# Getting error as "initializing endpoint: java.net.BindException: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:8080" while installing JBoss AS7

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ip, jboss7.x

Here I've installed `JBoss AS 7.1` in `AWS ec-2` linux instance.

Please help before marking it as **duplicate** as many SO questions are already available but nothing helped me here.

The server is running successfully

```
[root@ip-172-31-20-18 ~]# service jboss status
jboss-as is running (pid 10251)
```

It's only accessible for `http://localhost:8080` and from the other machines, here I want to access with `instance public IP`

Yes the server log says

```
06:55:04,657 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error initializing endpoint: java.net.BindException: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:8080
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:190) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:983) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:267) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]

06:55:04,706 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.connector.http: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.connector.http: JBAS018007: Error starting web connector
        at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:271)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:8080
```

But I don't know why because already I've modified the `standalone.xml` in cofiguration dir.

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <!--
              ~  Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
              ~                  To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL
              -->
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```

But here the port **8080** is listening for all `IPs`

```
[root@ip-172-31-20-18 jboss]# netstat -tulpn

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10251/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10251/java
.. ... ... ... ...      ....    .....        .......                .....          ........
```

not at `localhost`.

Pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Someone help me out, how to access it from other machine. I'm not able to understand where to change the configuration?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting this but I'll be glad if you say the reason pls. Since I'm trying to solve this from last two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Sorry. The `configuration` of the server is all set and I was wasting my day to solving the issue in configuration.

All I needed to do is the creatation `Security rule` with port **8080** to the `Security group` of `AWS ec2 instance`.

And the server is accessible from remote machines.